# MS SQL Store Procedure to Merge Multiple Rows into Single Row based on Variable Table and Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm working with MS SQL Server 2008. I'm trying to create a stored procedure to Merge (perhaps) several rows of data (answers) into a single row on target table(s). This uses a 'table_name' field and 'column_name' field from the answers table. The data looks like something like this:

```
answers table
--------------
id int
table_name varchar
column_name varchar
answer_value varchar
```

So, the target table (insert/update) would come from the 'table_name'. Each row from the anwsers would fill one column on the target table.

```
table_name_1 table
--------------
id int
column_name_1 varchar
column_name_2 varchar
column_name_3 varchar
etc...
```

Note, there can be many target tables (variable from answers table: table_name_1, table_name_2, table_name_3, etc.) that insert into many columns (column_name_1...2...3) on each target table.

I thought about using a WHILE statement to loop through the answers table. This could build a variable which would be the insert/update statement(s) for the target tables. Then executing those statements somehow. I also noticed Merge looks like it might help with this problem (select/update/insert), but my MS SQL Stored Procedure experience is very little. Could someone suggestion a strategy or solution to this problem?

Note 6/23/2014: I'm considering using a single Merge statement, but I'm not sure it is possible.

Comment: The expected result are a bunch of tables with one row of data? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Serpiton - Yes, in most cases there might be (20+) answers rows that would need to be inserted into 1 row in the table_name table. I'm trying to do this dynamically if possible.

Comment: It can be done, but if you need the values in that particular format you get it by `PIVOT`ing them without creating the tables, is that part really necessary?

Comment: @Serpiton - BTW, I'm still learning MS SQL Stored Procedures. I'm more of a PHP developer. PIVOT'ing looks very promising. I'll give it a try. That should make the Merge more simple.

Comment: To find some examples of dynamic pivoting in SQLServer you can write (sql server dynamic pivot)[http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+dynamic+pivot] in the search box, I can also write a template in an answer. The important part, IMO, is if you really need the result in different tables or a resultset like `ID | table_name | answer_1 | ... | answer_n` is enough

Comment: @Serpiton - Thank you for your help. I finally succeeded last week in writing this complex stored procedure. The dynamic pivoting was required. I also had to build the merge query from within the stored procedure and then execute it. It's too complex to post as an answer.

Comment: If you think it'll be useful for someone else maybe you can post a simplified version, or a template with pseudocode

Comment: @Serpiton - It's just too much code to fit on one page. I would also need to change most variable/column namings, explain where the data is coming from, how the data is formatted, etc. It would take me a good part of a day to do so.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood the question, because `MERGE` is a sql command and I don't see where it apply to this, but a check [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd8237/24) to me it's not that much code

Comment: @Serpiton - Like I said, it was a complex solution. MERGE was used to do an update/insert using the pivoted data. I like your sqlfiddle. Post it to this thread and I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably missing something, but the basic idea to solve the problem is to use meta-programming, like a dynamic pivot.
In this particular case there is another layer to make the solution more difficult: the result need to be in different execution instead of beeing grouped.

The backbone for a possible solution is

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--using a cursor on SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM answers iterate:
--*Cursor Begin Here*
  --mock variable for the first value of the cursor
  DECLARE @table AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 't1'

  -- Column list
  SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct 
                               ',' + QUOTENAME(column_name)
                        FROM answers with (nolock)
                        WHERE table_name = @table
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                       ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                      , 1, 1, '')

  --Query definition
  SET @query = '
  SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
  INTO   ' + @table + '
  FROM   (SELECT column_name, answer_value 
          FROM   answers 
          WHERE  table_name = ''' + @table + ''') b
         PIVOT (MAX(answer_value) FOR column_name IN (' + @cols + ' )) p '

  --select @query

  EXEC sp_executesql @query

  --select to verify the execution
  --SELECT * FROM t1
--*Cursor End Here*
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd8237/24)</kbd>

*The cursor definition is omitted, because I'm not sure if it'll work on SQLFiddle*

In addition to the template for a Dynamic Pivot the columns list is filtered by the new table name, and in the query definition there is a `SELECT ... INTO` instead of a `SELECT`.

This script does not account for table already in the database, if that's a possibility the query can be divided in two:

```
  SET @query = '
  SELECT TOP 0 ' + @cols + ' 
  INTO   ' + @table + '
  FROM   (SELECT column_name, answer_value 
          FROM   answers 
          WHERE  table_name = ''' + @table + ''') b
         PIVOT (MAX(answer_value) FOR column_name IN (' + @cols + ' )) p '
```

to create the table without data, if needed, and

```
  SET @query = '
  INSERT INTO   ' + @table + '(' + @cols + ')'
  SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
  FROM   (SELECT column_name, answer_value 
          FROM   answers 
          WHERE  table_name = ''' + @table + ''') b
         PIVOT (MAX(answer_value) FOR column_name IN (' + @cols + ' )) p '
```

or a `MERGE` to insert/update the values in the table.
Another possibility will be to `DROP` and recreate every table.

Answer (score 0):

Approach I took to this complex problem:

- Create several temporary tables to work with your data
- Select and populate the temporary tables with the data
- Use dynamic pivoting to pivot the rows into one row
- Use a CURSOR with WHILE loop for multiple table entries
- SET @query with the dynamically built MERGE statement
- EXECUTE(@query)
- Drop temporary tables